# fire jquery plugin after ajax loads content

Tags: jquery, plugins

I have an ajax'd site that where:

```
<div class="content" id="current_page1">the content< /div>
```

is swapped out depending on what page the user is on. I'd like to fire a jquery plugin when ajax loads my content

```
<div id="current_page1">the content< /div>
```

Is there any way jquery can tell if "current_page1" has been loaded? document(ready) obviously won't detect "current_page1" if "current_page1" is created/loaded through ajax.

Basically I'm looking for:

1. actively detect #current_page1
2. startPlugin()

Thanks in advance! I've seen lots of posts that seem somewhat relevant to what I'm looking for, but most of the relevant answers I've found relate to binding click events after an ajax load. I'm just looking to fire some plugins!

Comment: On your `$.ajax` `success` method, run whatever code you need to run (`StartPlugin()`)...

Comment: You can use jQuery.ajax instead of jQuery.load (I assume you that) - it gives you much more power with callbacks.

Comment: thanks for the help guys! I found a work around that makes my question irrelevant. I'd post the solution except it doesnt really relate to / answer the initial question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery deferreds here.  You can check out the [API here](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).  A pseudo code example for triggering a deferred when an AJAX call successfully resolves is below:

```
var ajaxDeferred = makeAJAXCall();
ajaxDeferred.then(function(){
    //whatever you want to happen when the deferred is resolved.
});

var makeAJAXCall = function(){
    var callComplete = new $.Deferred();
    $.ajax({
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            //resolve the deferred!
            callComplete.resolve(data);
        }
    });
    return callComplete.promise();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to append script to your ajax page:

```
<script> startPlugin() </script>
```

Better way would be to use a callback like the other answers suggest.